# Xbox 360 Wireless Controller Won't sync under Mac

Tags: xbox-360, macos, controllers

I have a genuine Xbox 360 wireless controller and a gaming receiver. I have downloaded the latest driver from [Tattiebogle.net](http://tattiebogle.net/index.php/ProjectRoot/Xbox360Controller/OsxDriver) and installed successfully.

I have MacOSX Lion installed and under System Information, the receiver is recognised as following:

```
Vendor-Specific Device:

  Product ID:   0x0291
  Vendor ID:    0x045e  (Microsoft Corporation)
  Version:  1.14
  Speed:    Up to 12 Mb/sec
  Location ID:  0xfa240000 / 9
  Current Available (mA):   500
  Current Required (mA):    260
```

When I installed first time, both receiver and the controller were synced up correctly, and showed the controller's information on Pref360Control, System Preferences.

However, later, the controller won't sync. On Pref360Controll, there is "No devices found".

What bugs me the most is that I had a controller going. Mac knew there was a controller and I could see it moving, rumbling and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was solved with a genuine gaming receiver.